# GNU screen prevent "Width x chars too small" message on exit ("C-a C-\")

Tags: gnu-screen

When the width of the currently focused pane (in the tmux sense) is too narrow to display the confirmation message `Really quit and kill all your windows [y/n]`, Screen displays `Width x chars too small` and doesn't accept `y` or `n`. Is there a way to get it to either display a truncated `y/n` message or disable the confirmation altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much to work with, without modifying `screen`.  The latter message comes from `Input`, and simply returns without providing a status code [(see source)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/input.c?id=ee3ba201b7725bdaabab6325baf55d9b47a73b5a):

`if (len < 0)
     {
       LMsg(0, "Width %d chars too small", -len);
      return;
     }`

Interestingly, that section was rewritten last year, removing the test but only commenting: [Use size_t for len](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/src/input.c?id=b62abacd4aed6a203ae53aab13af924a2c355ccd).  Likely the *reason* for removal was to fix a compiler warning (`size_t` is **positive**).

The [ChangeLog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/src/ChangeLog?id=513a5b50ea77f8809c3756b6449672a768ee2b44) does not mention this change; it may not even have been intentional:

```
+Version 4.3.0 (13/06/2015):
+  * Introduce Xx string escape showing the executed command of a window
+  * Implement dead/zombie window polling, allowing for auto reconnecting
+  * Allow setting hardstatus on first line
+
+  New Commands:
+  * 'sort' command sorting windows by title
+  * 'bumpleft', 'bumpright' - manually move windows on window list
+  * 'collapse' removing numbering 'gaps' between windows, by renumbering
+  * 'windows' command now accepts arguments for use with querying
+
```

So the most recent version (4.3.1) would not behave as you report.  At least, it will not prevent you from using the input-prompt.